# Regular expression with conditional repeat

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
^((_[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z])+((?<bracket>\[)[0-9]+(?<-bracket>\])(?(bracket)(?!)))?)$
```

I want this to repeat if there is a dot (`.`)

I know I can repeat the expression like this adding the dot (`.`)

```
^((_[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z])+((?<bracket>\[)[0-9]+(?<-bracket>\])(?(bracket)(?!)))?)(\.((_[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z])+((?<bracket>\[)[0-9]+(?<-bracket>\])(?(bracket)(?!)))?))*$
```

But I want to know if there is a better way, without copying the initial part.

Background:

I need to access a machine Micrologix 5000 which uses tag based addressing. In a C# application, I want to validate that the user input a good address.

Allowed:

- `Dog.Tail`
- `Dogs[0].Tail.IsMoving`

Not Allowed:

- `Dog.`
- `Dogs[0].`

Comment: why dot you use \.\1 tha backreference group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion. See this:

```
^((_[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z])+((?<bracket>\[)[0-9]+(?<-bracket>\])(?(bracket)(?!)))?)(\.\1)*$
                                                                                    ^^
```

- `\1` **recurses** the first sub-pattern within the first capturing group `( )`.

However, this is two steps less efficient than your attempted regex, which is optimal for this case. Recursion can be used here to increase its readability, but is not the recommended practice.

Comment: Recursion is the solution, but I had to use \1 in my case instead of ?1

Comment: It worked with basic test cases, but not using real case. \1 is used to repeat the same capture, but I needed to repeat the same pattern so the solution is (?R) that is not supported in .Net .